# Create a table out of a tibble

Tags: r

I do have the following `dataframe` with 45 million observations:

```
year month variable
 1992    1    0
 1992    1    1
 1992    1    1
 1992    2    0
 1992    2    1
 1992    2    0
```

My goal is to count the frequency of the variable for each month of a year.
I was already able to generate these sums with `cps_data` as my `dataframe` and `SKILL_1` as my `variable`.

```
cps_data %>%                                        
  group_by(YEAR, MONTH) %>%                         
  summarise_at(vars(SKILL_1),             
               list(name = sum))
```

Logically, I obtained 348 different rows as a tibble. Now, I struggle to create a new table with these values. My new table should look similar to my tibble. How can I do that? Is there even a way? I've already tried to read in an excel file with a date range from 01/1992 - 01/2021 in order to obtain exactly 349 rows and then merge it with the rows of the tibble, but it did not work..

```
     # A tibble: 349 x 3
# Groups:   YEAR [30]
    YEAR          MONTH  name
   <dbl>      <int+lbl> <dbl>
 1  1992  1 [January]     499
 2  1992  2 [February]    482
 3  1992  3 [March]       485
 4  1992  4 [April]       457
 5  1992  5 [May]         434
 6  1992  6 [June]        470
 7  1992  7 [July]        450
 8  1992  8 [August]      438
 9  1992  9 [September]   442
10  1992 10 [October]     427
# ... with 339 more rows
```

many thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is not clear whether your question is about 348 vs 349 row or not

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)

createmonthyear <- function(start_date,end_date){
ym <- seq(as.yearmon(start_date), as.yearmon(end_date), 1/12)

data.frame(start = pmax(start_date, as.Date(ym)),
           end = pmin(end_date, as.Date(ym, frac = 1)),
           month = month.name[cycle(ym)],
           year = as.integer(ym),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)}
```

Once you create the function, you can specify the start and end date you want:

```
left_table <- data.frame(createmonthyear(1991-01-01,2021-01-01))
```

then left join the output with what you have

```
library(dplyr)
right_table <- data.frame(cps_data %>%                                        
      group_by(YEAR, MONTH) %>%                         
      summarise_at(vars(SKILL_1),             
                   list(name = sum)))
    results <- left_join(left_table, right_table, by = c("Year" = "year", "Month" = "month")
```